# Characteristic Curve for Split Toning?

Tags: printing, darkroom, split-tone

We can see from the data sheet on Ilford Multigrade Paper ([link](https://www.ilfordphoto.com/amfile/file/download/file/1778/product/743/)) that the curve gets steeper with increased contrast and tonal range shrinks (as expected). Various techniques seek to maximize tonality, and I'm a fan of the split grade printing technique. Let's assume I've printed an image with the maximum tonality that I can achieve (given my artistic contrast needs, of course :-)

Now I'm going to split tone it in sepia. In the past, I've done this by trial and error to get something that I like. What my question is: is there any more scientific way of going about toning? What happens to the print's characteristic curve during toning? Can the coloration be quantified and graphed as a product of the original characteristic curve and some modifier for time in bleach and/or chemical dilution?

Just as I can look at a film characteristic curve and understand how much latitude I have to work with and (pending development) how much contrast as well...how can I have this same insight into toning?

Comment: Lookin’ at you jindra and Jim!

Comment: FYI, the link is dead...

Comment: @Pouya fixed. Really surprised ilford is movin things around on the site.

Comment: **No idea**. But more "scientific" would be making a series of controlled tests. Some gradient stripes? Some tables taking notes on time, temperature concentration or whatever variables you have?

Comment: @Rafael, yea. I’m most likely going to make my own tests and curves. Was really hoping someone would have done something similar in the past though